# Creating a portlet from existing WAR file

Tags: tomcat, portlet, war

I have an existing war file, nothing special about it, just a normal web application. I am making a portal page and I want to make this existing web application into a portlet. Anyone know how to go about doing that? Basically if I could just stick this war file into a portlet window, that would be great but I don't know where to begin.

I am using OpenPortal 2.x that has been installed on Tomcat 6.0.x and programming in Eclipse Helios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can package your portlet wars in the specified format and ensure you have a `portlet.xml` in addition to the `web.xml`

I have not used OpenPortal but I assume it is the portal framework that allows you to deploy your individual portlet as a war.

A diagram example is [available here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbportal/v2.4/reference-guide/en/html/tutorials.html). See **5.2.1.2. Package Structure** for more.

Another thing you can do is to [use this tutorial for OpenPortal and Eclipse](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&sqi=2&ved=0CCYQFjAC&url=http://oportlet.googlecode.com/files/Create%2520a%2520sample%2520portlet%2520with%2520Eclipse.doc&ei=kMXsTdmSJIewvgP-r7m-Dw&usg=AFQjCNEc6-cmfxwcK7LPpY42kaytOUlqzg&sig2=Cbo2xTW2EaUJu3SW_jt2QA), and create a sample portlet and export it as a war. Then compare the new war with your existing war, most likely you'll only need to add a couple of files - one of them being `portlet.xml`

Then deploy your modified war into the portal.

I've found some more samples for you, [take a look at these](http://java.net/projects/portlet-container/downloads/directory/samples) - you can directly compare your existing war to the structure of these. Try deploying some of these, so you'll know if they work on OpenPortal too.